# Is there a faster way to deploy WSIT Services than autodeploy?

Tags: performance, glassfish, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

We've recently upgraded our services technology stack. We opted for the WSIT implementation of JAX-WS.

Currently, we're relying on our Glassfish Application Server to deploy the web service automatically based on the JAX-WS annotations.

We have about two dozen different services and hundreds of operations, so this autodeployment takes quite a while.  Is there a faster way to deploy than autodeployment?

What I'm looking for is something that can do the work at compile time or build time instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but doesn't the wsgen / apt tools that come with Metro do the work of processing the annotations and building the artifacts for the web service? You could then include the location of the wsdl, and the classes, in the deployment unit. I'm not sure exactly how it's done though, hope this points you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Jamie, I've been looking into some of the WSGEN tools for ANT, and they seem like they may work.

Comment: Yeah, the wsgen and apt commands are probably what you're looking for. You can create a target in Ant to run them at build time. Maven also has the ability to incorporate them.

Glad I could help :)